# summation of values of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-functions

Say we have a random variable Y belonging to {-1,1}. Each time an ideal random number code-simulation generates a value for Y, using "Uniform distribution", let us give that value a symbol yi. So, each yi belongs to [-1,1]. eg: 10 random numbers generated can be [-0.9, -0.892, 0.23,...etc].If I want to sum =∑yi for very large i, can I say that X goes to '0'? Intuitively I feel so, but mathematically, I do not know what it should be. Can anyone help derive an analytical form here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you asked a similar question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406191/summation-of-cosine-of-uniform-random-variable.

Comment: You write $\{-1,1\}$ which denotes a set with only $2$ elements. It seems you meant to write $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Yes, I did ask, I did not know if I can ask another question there with ongoing discussion. If so, I will post it there.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant [-1,1].

Comment: If this is a continuation of the post on Cross-Validated, you can edit your post there itself. Or if you want to ask a different question here/there, that's fine.

Comment: It is similar but not same. It has different flavor of approach and so I want to treat it as independent question first and then understand comprehensively, the both answers for my purpose whose sub parts are these questions. Thanks for the kind notification.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nY_i$ indeed "goes to $0$" if $n$ increases.

Then similarly it must be true that $S_n-Y_1=\sum_{i=2}^nY_i$ "goes to $0$" if $n$ increases.

This however implies that $Y_1=0$ which definitely does not have to be the case.

So the assumption must be wrong.

Comment: from transiting to your second statement, inherent assumtion is 'n' is constant, but large. The moment we pushed Y1 into LHS, it means, we subtracted that Y1 from 0 (because S~0 is our assumption). So, the RHS, by default is deprived of Y1 and hence its true. Your conclusion that " goes to 0" if n increases can not be used here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "goes to $0$"? If the assumption is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=0$ almost surely  we must also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=2}^nY_i=0$ almost surely (do you agree with that?) then taking the limit on both sides gives $-Y_1=0$ almost surely, which is not true (so assumption is wrong). What I miss is some foregoing factor like $\frac1n$ (taking the average). That would rule $Y_1$ out.

Comment: I understand now! But is this a rigorous proof? When you say almost surely, is it definitely or approximately? If we take average, lim n ->inf makes it anyway zero on both sides. So, mean of Yi is indeed 0! if Yi belongs to [-1, 1].

Comment: $S_n\to 0$ almost surely means $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=0)=1$. My answer gives a rigorous proof that this is not the case here. With the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law) it can be shown that $\frac1nS_n\to0$ almost surely (i.e. $P(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1nS_n=0)=1$).